# page is redirecting to index on login

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication

I am creating a login system, my login and register script is working fine but when i started with page permission it did not work, it keeps on redirecting to the landing page

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include_once("scripts/global.php");
    if( $logged == 1 ){
        header("Location:home.php");
        exit();
    }
?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Webplex</title>
        <link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container center">
        <h1>Webplex</h1>
            <a href="register.php"><p>Register</p></a> | <a href="login.php"><p>Login</p> </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**global.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
include("scripts/connect.php");

//check the session
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $session_username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $session_pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
    $session_id = $_SESSION['id'];

    //check member
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM members WHERE `id` = '$session_id' AND `password` = '$session_pass' LIMIT 1") or die("could not perform");
    $count_count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count_count > 0){   
        //logged in stuff here
        $logged = 1;
    }else{
        $logged = 0;
        header("Location:logout.php");
        exit();
    }
}else if(isset($_COOKIE['id_cookie'])){
    $session_id = $_COOKIE['id_cookie'];
    $session_pass = $_COOKIE['pass_cookie'];

    //check member
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM members WHERE `id` = '$session_id AND `password` = '$session_pass' LIMIT 1")or die("could not perform");
    $count_count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count_count > 0){
        while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $session_username = $row['username'];
        }
        //create sessions
        $_SESSION['username'] = $session_username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $session_id;
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $session_pass;

        //logged in stuff here
        $logged = 1;
    }else{
        header("Location:logout.php");
        exit();
    }
}else{
    //not logged in
    $logged = 0;
}
?>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
    include_once("scripts/global.php");
    if( $logged == 0 ){
        header("Location:index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

I am being redirected as soon as I login,

Comment: Where is the code for login.php file?

Comment: your sql query checks the password for your session id, you should check the password for the entered username instead

Comment: Note: indent your code (better for debug), `mysql_` functions was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: Then what am i suppose to use ? @ChoiZ

Comment: password is correct as i have tried and put wrong password and it detects the wrong one @Fanax

Comment: @user3293299 you can use `mysqli_` functions or `pdo_mysql` check php doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check session for this :-

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("Location:home.php");
exit();
}
```

Comment: i did not understand you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why did you use this code in **home.php** ? 
When **$logged == 1** it mean user logged in the system and you redirect to the **home.php** once more. Does it make a loop?

```
if( $logged == 1 ){
    header("Location:home.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: sorry its not home.php file its actually index.php

Comment: the thing is stackoverflow is not letting me put more code